# sharing multiple blog posts

Tags: string, icons, sharing, social-media

I am trying to share different instances from the same page using **Social Sharing Buttons**. I have set up a Press Release page on my site to use a **'form and list'** module. This module displays a list of all press releases, and it also displays each specific post in the same module. Kind of like a page refresh within the same window.

Each post has a different string at the end of each url **(Example: udt_2246_param_detail=5)**. Instead of having the editor go in and update this link inside every post, I want to be able to have a url that will pick up the url string of the current post and only share "THAT" post not the list of posts.

I am using code from http://simplesharingbuttons.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** [SimpleSharingButtons.com](http://simplesharingbuttons.com/) now lets you do what you need with a little bit of JavaScript. My original answer is below:

There are two ways to do this.

1) With JavaScript:

You pretty much just need to add an onclick event that will open a new window with the sharing page. You will pass an encoded value of `document.URL` as the URL parameter

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURI(document.URL)); return false;"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
```

You can also refer [to this blog post](http://blog.fourtonfish.com/post/88277960745/the-original-use-case-i-had-in-mind-for-the-simple) for more details.

The problem with this solution is that you will either have to

a) use your main page for the fallback, so the code would look like this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=ENCODEDURLOFYOURMAINPAGE" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURI(document.URL)); return false;"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
```

b) or simply use the first version of the code above and have no non-JavaScript fallback

Also I'm not sure if the new window won't get blocked by a pop-up blocker.

2) A much better solution would be using PHP (or any other server-side language):

If it's possible for you to use PHP, you could use [this code snippet](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/get-current-page-url/) to create a getURL function in PHP:

```
<?php
function getUrl() {
$url  = @( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != 'on' ) ? 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] :  'https://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$url .= ( $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] !== 80 ) ? ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : "";
$url .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
return $url;
}
?>
```

Then you can use this code:

```
<ul class="share-buttons">
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode(getUrl()); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="images/flat_web_icon_set/color/Facebook.png"></a></li>
</ul>
```